# Weird PHP namespace issue

Tags: php

I am working on a library and I have "other" libraries it uses that get included via composer. So in one of my libraries I need to use Buzz so I have

```
<?php

namespace mynamespace;

use Buzz\Browser,
    Buzz\Client\Client;

class Stuff
{
    public function stuff()
    {
        $stuff = new Browser(new Curl());
    }
}
```

Buzz is https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz

But I am getting an error

```
Class 'mynamespace\Curl' not found
```

Now I don't seem to grasp why `new Browser(new Curl());` is not referencing the `Buzz\Browser`. If I change it to new `\Buzz\Browser(new Buzz\Client\Client());` it works fine. I checked composer, it is all fine and including stuff correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I don't seem to grasp why new Browser(new Curl()); is not referencing the Buzz\Browser

It is. The class `Curl` is not defined in your namespace, you'd need another `use` statement to import `Buzz\Client\Curl`.

```
<?php
namespace mynamespace;

use Buzz\Browser,
    Buzz\Client\Curl;

class Stuff
{
    public function stuff()
    {
        $stuff = new Browser(new Curl());
    }
}
```

Or if `Curl` is a class in the root namespace you can precede it with a backslash and remove the import statement.

```
<?php
namespace mynamespace;

use Buzz\Browser;

class Stuff
{
    public function stuff()
    {
        $stuff = new Browser(new \Curl());
    }
}
```

Comment: lol +_+ this is what I get for coding on a weekend, my brain is apparently dead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The message doesn't say it can't find Buzz\Browser. It actually does find it. The message says it cannot find mynamespace\Curl - this is because Curl resides in the top level namespace and not in mynamespace.

Solution:

- either add `use Curl;` to the use list, or
- use the backslash when instantiating: `new \Curl()`

HTH